# How to verify live video is playing using selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, video-player

I am testing a website which streams a live TV Channel, using selenium I have navigated to the live TV channel page and now I want to verify that live tv video is being displayed.

Please advise on how I can verify live tv video is being played using selenium c#

I've tried inspecting the element on the video player, I've also looked into JavaScriptExecutor Methods such as executeScript

I've tried the following:

```
public bool? IsLiveVideoPlaying()
{
    if (IsElementExist(LiveVideoPlayer))
    {
       Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }
    return (string)GetCurrentVideoStatus() == "playing";
}

public object GetCurrentVideoStatus()
{
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)SeleniumDriver.Instance;
 return js.ExecuteScript("return testData.status");
 }
```